# Saving the uploaded image in server folder with different sizes

Tags: php, image, upload

Here is my code where I have been trying for few hours to save the uploaded image in server folder with different sizes. But however image is not getting saved and unable to get where it goes wrong. Previously I used to write with binary as in my second code part below by bringing binary data somehow from my mobile side(The pic is taken from the camera and sent on the fly from mobile). But as this increases data. I decided to use even to upload image file with multipart-type file upload from my mobile side too.

```
<?php

$imagefile = $_FILES["uploadphoto1"]["name"];
$errors=0;
$uploadPath  = __DIR__."/contents/uploads";
define ("MAX_SIZE","4000");

$imagename = "testingimage";

if($imagefile)
{
    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['uploadphoto1']['name']);
    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);

if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif"))
    {
        echo ' Unknown Image extension ';
        $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {

        $file1 = $_FILES['uploadphoto1']['tmp_name'];

        thumbnail_image($file1, "640", "480",$uploadPath.$imagename);
        thumbnail_image($file1, "480", "340",$uploadPath.$imagename."_preview");

    }
}else{
    echo "No file is inserted>>>>>>>>>";
}

function thumbnail_image($original_file_path, $new_width, $new_height, $save_path="")
{
    $imgInfo = getimagesize($original_file_path);
    $imgExtension = "";

    switch ($imgInfo[2])
    {
        case 1:
            $imgExtension = '.gif';
            break;

        case 2:
            $imgExtension = '.jpg';
            break;

        case 3:
            $imgExtension = '.png';
            break;
    }

    if ($save_path=="") $save_path = "thumbnail".$imgExtension ;

    // Get new dimensions
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($original_file_path);

    // Resample
    $imageResample = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    if ( $imgExtension == ".jpg" )
    {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_file_path);
    }
    else if ( $imgExtension == ".gif" )
    {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($original_file_path);
    }
    else if ( $imgExtension == ".png" )
    {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($original_file_path);
    }

    imagecopyresampled($imageResample, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    if ( $imgExtension == ".jpg" )
        imagejpeg($imageResample, $save_path.$imgExtension);
    else if ( $imgExtension == ".gif" )
        imagegif($imageResample, $save_path.$imgExtension);
    else if ( $imgExtension == ".png" )
        imagepng($imageResample, $save_path.$imgExtension);

}

function getExtension($str) {

    $i = strrpos($str,".");
    if (!$i) { return ""; }

    $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
    return $ext;
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors)
{
    echo "Image Uploaded Successfully!";

}else{
    echo "Image uploading failed>>>>>>>";
     }

?>
```

But the below works with the same function when I used to get binary data, but this code is not included in my present code at all:

```
$file1   = tempnam($uploadPath, 'image1');
$fp1     = fopen($file1, 'wb');
fwrite($fp1, $binary1);// Here I have binary data of image. 
fclose($fp1);

thumbnail_image($file1, "640", "480",$uploadPath.$imagelastid.".jpg");

thumbnail_image($file1, "480", "340",$uploadPath.$imagelastid."_preview.jpg");
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me solve this and put me in right track.

I get this **error**:

```
getimagesize(): Read error! in C:\xampp\htdocs\MOBILE_PHP\imagephptest.php on line 48
```

where 48 line is --> $imgInfo = getimagesize($original_file_path);

Sometimes I get this error on the same line.

`getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\MOBILE_PHP\imagephptest.php` on line 44

Comment: do you get any error message?

Comment: where does it stop working as expected?

Comment: @VladPreda Have edited my question

Comment: I can't really find any info on it, but since $_FILES['uploadphoto1']['tmp_name'] is temporary copy of the file, perhaps you can't manipulate it in anyway you want? try using move_uploaded_file() to save it somewhere and then pass the path to saved file to your function, and when it's complete, just delete the moved file.

Comment: @Darvex Okay. Then is it not a temporary file in my second code $file1 where I used to send it to manipulate previously?

Comment: @Korhan good point! Although i'd still give move_uploaded_file() a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($original_file_path);
$widthheight="$width X $height";
```

This will give image width and height to begin with.

Comment: I believe this doesn't solve my problem. Because I am getting error on different part. Please answer according to the error I get.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect that the problem is in these 2 lines:

```
$file1 = $_FILES['uploadphoto1']['tmp_name'];
$file1   = tempnam($uploadPath, 'image1');
```

You get the temporary name of uploaded image and save it in $file1, then right after that you rewrite that value and create temporary file. After that you pass it to your function and when you try

```
getimagesize($original_file_path);
```

it fails because $original_file_path is not even an image.

Comment: I didn't get any problem when I used this tempnam code. Please read my above description and I have clearly mentioned that I used to do that when I had binary data with no issues, but now I am using the first code snippet.

Comment: you opened the file you created and wrote binary data into it, giving getimagesize() something to work with. Now, you just pass empty file

Comment: Pleas see my edit. I haven't used tempnam in my first code snippet. I have a problem in that code. But not with second code. I used to write binary data, but I am no more using it.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest that you start the process after you test $_FILES["uploadphoto1"]['size']>0, not name or anything else. Also I suggest that you test the $original_file_path in your function before you start working with it. Also try to print/echo $original_file_path at the begging of the function to see what you get there.

As a side note, if you can use Imagick, use that, you don't need that much code.